# Changing Variables In Different handlers

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am creating variables and random numbers and i cant access them from other handlers in my script. Is there a way to make variables to access in all of my event handlers? My integer in my form handler cannot edit my variable in my button1 handler. Please Help, Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace IqTest


{


public partial class Form1 : Form
{





    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        Random rand = new Random();
        int ran = rand.Next(70, 100);
        string mystring = ran.ToString();
        label2.Text = mystring;
    }

    private void checkBox11_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int ran = 0;
    }








}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare your integer as a class level variable and then it will be accessible by both event handlers.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace IqTest


{


public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int ran;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        Random rand = new Random();
        ran = rand.Next(70, 100);
        string mystring = ran.ToString();
        label2.Text = mystring;
    }

    private void checkBox11_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ran = 0;
    }

}
}
```